# Batch File: FindStr in AD group

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find out whether a user belongs to a certain Active Directory (AD) group by using a Batch Script.

I'm using the `FINDSTR` function to search for a specific string but it does not seem to find an exact string match.

e.g.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

REM check if the file exists
IF NOT EXIST "C:\APPS\UserGroups.txt" (
rem CREATE UserGroups file
> "C:\APPS\UserGroups.txt" dir
echo UserGroups.txt Created!
)

REM List AD groups associated with this user
whoami /groups > "C:\APPS\UserGroups.txt"

REM check if they are a domain admins in AD
FINDSTR  /c:"AERO\\Domain Admins" C:\APPS\UserGroups.txt

PAUSE
```

The current script verifies that the user is in the group **AERO\Domain Admins**. However, if I remove an "s" and search **AERO\Domain Admin** instead, it still shows that the user exists in the list.

Comment: What's the real goal? There are easier ways to output the members of the `Domain Admins` group; e.g. (PowerShell): `Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins"`.

Comment: The script is run by users to check which groups they are in and based on the groups, it will copy in installation files to their computer so they can run certain programs.

Comment: So after reading the help file file for the `FINDSTR` command you could not come up with an option that would rectify this?

Comment: What is the point of your code that checks if the file exists and then creates the file.  It has no purpose.  Once you run the `whoami` command it creates the file and overwrites any existing file that was already present.

Comment: I would recommend using Group Policy Preferences rather than scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because FINDSTR does a substring search by default.

This does not guarantee the correct result, but it should get you closer:

```
FINDSTR  /rc:"\<AERO\\Domain Admins\>" C:\APPS\UserGroups.txt
```

It is a regular expression that guarantees the search string matches beginning and ending word boundaries.

**EDIT in response to comment**

My suggestion would fail if your search has n words, and there exists a group that starts with the same n words, and has one or more additional words tacked on.

For example `"\<word1\>"` would match `word1 word2`

Comment: This works great - but can you share an example of when this might not work so I'm aware as I'm not too family with regular expressions.

Comment: @Justin - The FINDSTR regular expression syntax is very non-standard, so don't think this applies to other regex engines. But I've explained a potential failure in my edit.